# collection was not processed by flush() exception In JPA

Tags: jpa

I have the Entities as follows;

```
Claimant:

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "payTo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotAudited
    private Set<Payment> payments = new HashSet<Payment>();

Payment:
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rofOf", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    private Set<Payment> returnOfFundings = new HashSet<Payment>();
```

When doing claimant.merge()

getting the following exception "**collection [com.bfds.saec.domain.Payment.returnOfFundings] was not processed by flush()**"

for the above one solution i found that just reload the Claimant with joining with Payment before merge.

But Please let me know,Is there any other way is there to solve the above problem as i don't want to reload the Claimant with payment.

What may be the root-cause for the problem ?? Is there any problem the relation I have defined there??

Answer (score 1):

Root cause of problem seems to be [HHH-273](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2763) bug in Hibernate. According comments it also pops up when Envers touches collection. Because it is fixed in version 4.0.1, best way to get rid of it is to update Hibernate.

Comment: The link seems to be broken. I think it refers to https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2763